# How to prevent ag-Grid unnecessary full width

Tags: css, ag-grid

I've read https://www.ag-grid.com/react-data-grid/grid-size/#top but still haven't figured out:

How can I make the table's width behave like `auto` so that it doesn't unnecessarily expand to the full width, taking up the entire window even when its contents don't require it?

[image]

See code at https://plnkr.co/edit/utQf6RGASwFVfGhW?preview

Also, a second attempt uses flexbox but still does not achieve what I'm hoping for: https://plnkr.co/edit/INyJbF4ZcydT0gUz